# In The Rise of Skywalker, what killed this character?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *The Rise of Skywalker*, the protaganists track the assassin/bounty hunter Ochi of Bestoon to a planet where they get sucked undergound and find

> his decomposed remains.

My initial assumption was that he was unable to find a way out of the tunnels and died there, and the plot would center around the heroes trying to find a way out. But in the following scences they

> walk out of the tunnels with no fanfare or explanation as to how they did so.

Are we supposed to assume that he

> was killed by by the giant worm thing? The inference was it only attacked because it was wounded and it slinked away after Rey healed it.

So what actually killed this person?

Comment: The follow up question should be asked as a new question.

Comment: Iirc your second spoiler is incorrect, and was only made possible by the last part of your third spoiler.

Comment: It seems a little pedantic to ask what killed someone when they fell into a underground tunnel system made by a giant worm that seems more than willing to kill people.  Huh, that man in the cage with the lion is dead.  I wonder what killed him?

Comment: @JPhi1618 I see your point, but before the worm thing I expected that the dude had just not been able to find a way out and our heroes would similarly struggle. But their escape was just hand waved away. Was the worm thing really the only thing stopping anyone from getting out? There must have been other ways around him.

Comment: @Darren, I really thought the worm would punch a hole for them to get out or lead them to an exit rather than just moving a bit and revealing a giant convenient hole...  That did seem a little hand waved.  I think that was done quick to move the story along.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The film's [official *extended novelisation*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition) suggests that he died of injuries sustained in his original fall into the tunnels. His skeleton is found near to his (broken) speeder, a few feet from the entrance and appears to be largely complete, strongly suggesting that he wasn't killed by an animal that then ate him.

> Ochi’s speeder had fallen into the tunnel, and **either he’d died on impact, or he’d injured himself so badly that he’d died slowly, trapped and alone.**
>
> BB-8 warbled that he’d found something.
>
> **Rey moved next to him and peered closer at the pile of bones. Tattered clothes clung to the remains. A leather belt with a knife sheath circled his pelvis.** The sheath was empty.

Comment: So are they using the novels to explain all the glaring plot holes?

Comment: @Darren - Ever since the prequel era, Lucasfilm have aggressive pursued a policy of intentionally leaving plot points unexplained in the films i*n order to have them answered in the books, factbooks and other media*, creating a 360-degree marketing strategy.

Answer (score 37):

#### Unknown

*Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker - The Visual Dictionary* touches on this but just states it was unknown what happened to him.

> Ochi's bones now litter a vexis lair beneath the Shifting Mires of Lurch Canyon. What fate befell him is unknown, but his bones have long since been picked clean by gouge-beetles.

It's worth noting though that the Vexis only let Rey and the group out of the tunnels when Rey healed it. As such it is safe to assume either the Vexis attacked and killed Ochi or did not let him out of the tunnel and so he starved to death because he could not escape.

Comment: I'm holding off upvoting or accepting this answer. Whilst it might be the best we can do given the information available, it's bascially saying "either this or that killed him". I'd like to know if it was this or that.

Comment: @Darren The official answer from the Visual Dictionary is "Unknown". There might be a more specific one but I haven't found it and I'd be surprised if there was. At the moment Unknown plus some informed speculation is the best we have.